# Locating VMCS in memory

Tags: intel, virtualization, ept, vt-x

I'm learning about Intel Virtualization stack and wondering if there is a possible way of spotting VMCS?

Let's say I'm running VMware Workstation on Windows or Linux and I have couple of VM's running. How can I spot VMCS for each running VM? I am running a kernel module as well.

Or how can I get Extended Page Table Pointer for each VM?

Is that even possible to do for Type-1 hypervisors? As there is no *host* OS per se?

Thanks

Comment: The `vmptrst` instruction (used in the VMM) stores a pointer to the current VMCS.   But you can't read the memory directly, you have to use `vmread` to access the fields. There's no way to directly get the VMCS running on a different CPU.  You would have to know the VMM's data structures to find them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I hope you don't mind if I ask couple of follow up question for further clarification.
- What do you mean by different CPU? Different CPU Core?
- What do you mean by current VMCS? In case of a Type-1 hypervisor, is the current VMCS is going to be the host OS?

Thanks